# Release MFMAilComposeViewController after presentModalViewController: crashes

Tags: ipad, ios, memory-management, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have the following block of code which works fine in the simulator and on most devices, on some devices however (all on the same iOS version 4.2.1) the app is crashing when it gets to the `[mailComposer release]` call, does anyone have any insight on why this would be happening?

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposer setSubject:[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, \n\n Here is the link we discussed. \n %@", [self.webView.request URL]] isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    [mailComposer release];
```

Comment: `presentModalViewController` retains its view controller and releases it when it is popped, so I don't know why this would cause a crash.

Comment: That was my understanding as well, one thing I just thought of. I am presenting an "Email Link" button in an `UIActionSheet` using `showFromBarButtonItem:animated:`. Could there be some kind of UIKit collision when that popover is dismissed and the modal view is being presented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed to figure out what was causing my issue with the help of my new iPad 2.

The issue was caused by not having any mail accounts configured, simply adding

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
```

before I create and present the view prevents the crashing, in my `else` block I added an `UIAlertView` to let the user know they cannot access that feature without first configuring a mail account.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem and I really have NO idea why it would crash, because presentModalViewController is supposed to retain the view controller. After fighting with it, I finally just added a property on my view controller which retained the reference to the mfMailComposeViewController and it worked fine. :/

```
MFMailComposeViewController* mfMailComposeViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MFMailComposeViewController *mfMailComposeViewController;
```

then..

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:subject];
[controller setBody:body];
self.mfMailComposeViewController = controller;
[controller release];
```

Comment: That sucks! Not that it is a bad solution, I was planning to do the same thing, but it's just lame that you gotta do that... Seriously doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Upvoted, gonna wait to see if anyone can shed some more light though.